# Trouble with pointers and stack implementation

Tags: c, pointers, stack

I am trying to create a program that implements a stack in C.

Currently, my stack is showing up empty.

I think this is because I pass the stack but not a pointer to the stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node * ptr;
}node;

//create
//push
//pop
//destroy
//display
void push(int, node * top_node);
void pop(node * top_node);
void destroy(node * top_node);
void display(node * top_node);
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    node * top_node = NULL;

    push(1, top_node);
    push(5, top_node);
    push(55, top_node);
    display(top_node);
    pop(top_node);
    display(top_node);
    pop(top_node);
    display(top_node);
    pop(top_node);
    display(top_node);
    push(1, top_node);
    display(top_node);
    destroy(top_node);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void display(node * top_node)
{
    node * temp = top_node;
    if(top_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("The stack is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n ", temp-> info);
        temp = top_node -> ptr;
    }
}

void push(int data, node * top_node)
{
    if(top_node == NULL)
    {
        top_node = (struct node **) malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
        top_node ->ptr = NULL;
        top_node -> info = data;         
    }
    else
    {
        node * temp = (struct node *) malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
        temp -> ptr = top_node;
        temp -> info = data;
        top_node = &temp;
    }  
}

void pop(node * top_node)
{
    node * new_top = top_node;
    if(new_top == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nERROR, the stack is empty");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        new_top = new_top -> ptr;
        printf("popped value = %d", top_node -> info);
        free(top_node);
        top_node = new_top;
    }
}

void destroy(node * top_node)
{
    node * temp = top_node;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = top_node -> ptr;
        free(top_node);
        top_node = temp;
        temp = temp->ptr;   
    }
    free(temp);
}
```

The output that I am getting is this:

> The stack is empty
>   ERROR, the stack is emptyThe stack is empty
>   ERROR, the stack is emptyThe stack is empty
>   ERROR, the stack is emptyThe stack is empty
>   The stack is empty
>   
>   RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 227ms)

I believe that I should pass a pointer to stack, I tried implementing it but it shot out a bunch of errors.

Any step in the direction without giving me the full answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `1 * sizeof ...`???? And don't cast `malloc()`.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings, and fix them.  You have some pointer type mismatches, which is never good.

Comment: "RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 227ms)" - According to your output your code is correct. Strange enough.

Comment: See my answer, for issues in addition to the one identified by other answerers.

Comment: why did I get downvoted? I am new to this site and so far it doesn't seem very new-user friendly.

Comment: I think that could be because you could have studied these concepts by reading some tutorials too. Also, you could have looked at some sample code that is easily available on the web. This is just my opinion, the actual downvoters may have had other reasons. Btw I did not down vote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the issue, about the **call by value** to `top_node`, identified by both **iharob** and **Cherubim Anand**, there are other issues as well:

- All functions that have to modify `top_node` have to get its address passed in using `node **` except `display` because it just reads `top_node` without having to modify it.
- The call to such a modifying function will have to pass in the address of `top_node`, using `&` operator like `pop(&top_node);`, instead of passing its value, as is done for `display` function like `display(top_node);`.
- The usage of `top_node` inside such functions will have to use one level of dereferencing using `*` operator like `*top_node` except in `display`, where only the value is being passed.
- In the `display` function the line `temp = top_node -> ptr;` will always set `temp` to the second element causing the loop to iterate forever. It should instead be `temp = temp->ptr;`.
- `(struct node **) malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));` in `push` is incorrect and should be changed to `(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`. Any number multiplied by `1` remains unchanged.
- The last two statements in `destroy` function were erroneous and had to be removed to preserve correct functionality.

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *ptr;
}node;

//create
//push
//pop
//destroy
//display
void push(int, node ** top_node);
void pop(node ** top_node);
void destroy(node ** top_node);
void display(node * top_node);
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    node *top_node = NULL;

    push(1, &top_node);
    push(5, &top_node);
    push(55, &top_node);
    display(top_node);
    pop(&top_node);
    display(top_node);
    pop(&top_node);
    display(top_node);
    pop(&top_node);
    display(top_node);
    push(1, &top_node);
    display(top_node);
    destroy(&top_node);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void display(node * top_node)
{
    node * temp = top_node;
    if(top_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("The stack is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", temp->info);
        temp = temp->ptr;
    }
}

void push(int data, node ** top_node)
{
    if(top_node == NULL)
    {
        *top_node =  (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        (*top_node)->ptr = NULL;
        (*top_node)-> info = data;
    }
    else
    {
        node * temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp -> ptr = *top_node;
        temp -> info = data;
        *top_node = temp;
    }
}

void pop(node ** top_node)
{
    node * new_top = *top_node;
    if(new_top == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR, the stack is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        new_top = new_top -> ptr;
        printf("Popped value = %d\n", (*top_node)-> info);
        free(*top_node);
        *top_node = new_top;
    }
}

void destroy(node ** top_node)
{
    node * temp = *top_node;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = (*top_node)-> ptr;
        free(*top_node);
        *top_node = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as pass by reference in [tag:c].

Comment: Thank you, this falls in line with what everyone else has said. Should one cast `malloc()` ? There seems to be a discrepancy there. I think the `destroy()` function makes sense. If you are always checking temp to be equal to NULL then you are looking at the next object in the stack. Correct? Therefore you are always freeing the item above temp. Is this the wrong way to think about it?

Comment: @thutchi If you cast `malloc()` you risk a lot. [Read here for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495). Also, you can't pass a variable by reference in [tag:c], what you can do is pass a pointer to the memory location the data is stored in, that's very different. You need to dereference the pointer to alter it whereas you don't need to do anything special with a variable that is a reference. Notably, [tag:c++] has pass by reference, so mixing these concepts can become a problem.

Comment: @iharob that makes sense now. In school we were taught with casting. weird. I do have one more question when @Ahmed Akhtar frees `top_node` in the `destroy()` function he does not `free(temp)` I ran this through a memory leak checker and it works the way he wrote it. So, why don't we have to`free(temp)`

Comment: @thutchi The destroy function basically stores the next element for a while in `temp` and then `free`s the previous element and then resets `top_node` to the next element previously stored in `temp`.This way all memory gets freed up and there remains no question of freeing up `temp`.

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar I think I am beginning to understand what is happening. The wording may not be correct but this is what I am thinking:  temp still holds the pointers to the address of the data in 'current_node`. therefore, you are freeing the information that temp was pointing to anyways, because both pointers point to the same place. Is that the correct way to look at it?

Comment: @thutchi After this line `temp = (*top_node)-> ptr;` temp points to the next element in line, which may also be `NULL`, and `top_node` points to the previous element which needs to be deleted before moving `top_node` forward.

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar Ahh!  I understand it now. Thank you for helping me get some cobwebs out of the brain.

Comment: @thutchi Glad to help. An upvote would help, I too am a university student like you.

Comment: @iharob Thanks, I have done that. That would be a great help and display of sportsmanship.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to `top_node` in `push()` has no effect because that pointer is declared locally and only exists in the stack frame of the `push()` function itself. Instead you could pass a pointer to the pointer that is declared in the `main()` function, like this

```
void 
push(int data, node **top_node)
{
    if (*top_node == NULL)
    {
        *top_node = malloc(sizeof(**top_node));
        if (*top_node == NULL)
            return; // maybe warn about the error or abort the whole program
        (*top_node)->ptr = NULL;
        (*top_node)->info = data;
    }    
    else
    // append the node       
}
```

Otherwise, the allocated space is lost forever causing a memory leak, because the pointer that was holding it's adderss is destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, for my solution. I had this at one point but I could not get it to recognize top_node as a struct when assigning the pointer and the data. I assume that is because I left out the parenthesis.

Comment: @thutchi More precisely, [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: okay thank you. I think I understand what is going on now. First time making a stack, and its been a few years since linked lists. thank you.

Comment: Great work being the first one to identify the primary issue.